# Search entire server for a certain file type larger than 1GB in size?

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following linux command I use to determine if a directory is larger than 1GB in size:

```
du -sh * | sort -hr | awk '$1 ~ /[GT]/
```

How would I modify this to instead search for any file that has a certain file type, such as `.log` filetype?

Comment: The duplicate and the answers here will all descend into subdirectories; but it's easy to restrict `find` to not do that if you want to only examine the current directory - use `-maxdepth 0`

Answer (score 0):

Better use [find](/questions/tagged/find) :

```
find . -type f -name '*.log' -size +1G
```

Comment: when i run that in my terminal, it returns nothing/new line

Comment: Then you don't have a log file > 1GB

Comment: makes sense. if i wanted to search for 500MB or something i just simply replaece the `+1GB` with `+500MB`?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo find /www-data -name "*.log" -type f -size +1000000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }' | sort
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.